# why is bootstrap not running in my new angular application

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

So after starting a brand new angular project, I did an npm install of bootstrap. After seeing it in my node_modules, I then put it in my angular.json.

```
"styles": [
              "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

I am currently using example code of the classes that should be working in bootstrap, however when displayed on the screen they lack the bootstrap styling. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might me using a feature that requires bootstrap js too, so for that you also need to add  => "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" in the projects->architect->build->scripts array.
If that wasn't the case or it didn't work, you can try another method which is to directly import the css file in the style.css :

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```